# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission loadLibrary.jacob) WEBUTIL

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I configured WEBUTIL on Oracle Forms 10g and Oracle Apps ERP System. I am using built-in package CLIENT_OLE2 for generate Excel File from Oracle form on button trigger WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED. After click on button form freezes and they cannot do anything. I get these exceptions

```
Oracle JInitiator: Version 1.3.1.22
Using JRE version 1.3.1.22-internal Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator
Proxy Configuration: Browser Proxy Configuration
JAR cache enabled
 Location: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Oracle Jar Cache
 Maximum size: 50 MB
 Compression level: 0

----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
q:   hide console
s:   dump system properties
t:   dump thread list
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
Loading http://192.168.10.110/forms/java/frmall_jinit.jar from JAR cache
Loading http://192.168.10.110/forms/java/frmwebutil.jar from JAR cache
Loading http://192.168.10.110/forms/java/jacob.jar from JAR cache
proxyHost=null
proxyPort=0
connectMode=HTTP, native.
Forms Applet version is : 10.1.2.0
Exception occurred during event dispatching:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission loadLibrary.jacob)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkLink(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<clinit>(Dispatch.java:537)
at oracle.forms.webutil.ole.OleFunctions.create_obj(OleFunctions.java:398)
at oracle.forms.webutil.ole.OleFunctions.getProperty(OleFunctions.java:189)
at oracle.forms.handler.UICommon.onGet(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onGetHandler(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processSet(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onMessageReal(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processEventEnd(Unknown Source)
at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.LWComponent.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.LWComponent.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How to solve this problem?